# Swift give specific text if textField is empty

Tags: ios, swift, uitextfield

I would like to check if textField is empty or not and if empty, give specific text. 
I tried like below but it returns ""

```
let text = textField.text ?? "abc"
let value = ["text": text]
//put firebase database
ref.child("text").setValue(value)
```

How can I fix this? Thank you in advance!

Comment: you can use placeholder property to set default text when textfield is empty.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem is you always get an empty string that's not nil. You can correct that as following:

```
let text = (textField.text ?? "").isEmpty ? "abc" : textField.text
```

Comment: In that case you have to keep in mind that you end up with an optional String though.

Comment: If you don't want `text` to be an Optional String, simply force-unwrap the second occurrence of textField.text in this answer: `let text = (textField.text ?? "").isEmpty ? "abc" : textField.text!`.

Comment: Thank you for the comments! `guard let text = (textField.text ?? "").isEmpty ? "abc" : textField.text else { return }` I did like this. Is this bad approach?

Comment: With a guard like that you will return without doing anything if textfield.text is nil. If you want `text` to contain "abc" when textField.text is nil, that's not what you want.

Comment: You may just force unwrap it because the first condition already checks that the value not nil

Answer (score 1):

You have to make sure that the `text` property is not nil and also that it does not contain an empty string:

```
let text: String
if let textFieldText = textField.text, !textFieldText.isEmpty {
    text = textFieldText
} else {
    text = "abc"
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Modifying Anton's answer slightly, you could use:

```
let text = (textField.text ?? "").isEmpty ? "abc" : textField.text!
```

(Force-unwrapping the 2nd occurrence of `textField.text` so `text` isn't an optional.)

In that case force-unwrapping is safe because the first `??` "nil coalescing operator will have handled the case where `textField.text == nil`.

If you don't want to use a force-unwrap, break the conversion into 2 lines:

```
let required = str ?? ""
let text = required.isEmpty ? "abc" : required
```

Daibaku, the solution you showed in the comments:

```
guard let text = (textField.text ?? "").isEmpty ? "abc" : textField.text else { 
  return 
}
print(text)
```

Will return without executing the print statement (or whatever follows the guard) if `textField.text == nil`

Comment: Thank you so much for the very detailed explanation!!  I tried unwrap it and it worked perfectly. Thank you for your kindness:)